# SSL cannot establish secure connection - with Rails 6 app using Devise in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

As the title says, I have a Rails 6 app running in Heroku, with the automatic SSL certificate that Heroku provides.
Everything works great, and I can visit any page and it gets the `https` working fine. However, there is one exception:
When users sign up and they get the confirmation email, **clicking the link does not work** for some reason (see attached screenshots below), and the same happens even if you copy+paste the link in a new tab, of course.

- Ruby version: 2.7.1p83
- Rails version: 6.0.3.1

[image: Safari screenshot]
Firefox:
[image]

This is what I get when trying to access that url `https://my_domain.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=foobar`.

My `environments/production.rb` has these settings:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # a few more non important things, and then:
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'my_domain.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }


  config.force_ssl = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'my_domain.com' }
end
```

And this is what it looks like in Heroku:

[image]

I have these routes for Devise:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations',
                                    confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }
  authenticated :user do
    root to: "depots#index", as: :authenticated_root
  end

  root to: "public/welcome#index"
end
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    authenticated_root_path
  end
end
```

Do you guys have any idea on what could be wrong? And if not, any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE Aug, 04, 2020:**

I had added this redirect to my domain but even though it works redirecting from `grownis.com` to `www.grownis.com` it doesn't for `https://grownis.com`

[image]

Comment: To clarify - you said SSL is working when you visit the site.  So you're able to pull up other routes, just not that specific devise route?  What happens if you manually change the link to HTTP instead of HTTPS?  Do you see anything in your logs when you make the request that fails?

Comment: @Justin That is correct. Every other route is working fine, something seems to be odd with that one. If I change the url from https to http, it's automatically back to https and triggers the same error

Comment: gotcha - and what about the logs?  Honestly this seems like something weird (and maybe temporary) going on at Heroku.  I would also try restarting dynos.

Comment: Tried `heroku logs --ps router` and `heroku logs` but the request doesn't show up at all there. Tried restarting dynos and the issue is still there...

Comment: Ah ok, I'm out of ideas.  Although if the request doesn't show up in the logs at all that means its not even hitting Heroku, at least according to them.

Comment: Are you sure the domain in the email is correct?

Comment: @NeK yes, I triple-checked that. The domain is correct, and everything else looks just fine

Comment: I see. It's really weird issue. Can you give me the link to the website, so that I can check on my end?

Comment: @NeK yeah, the domain is www.grownis.com

Comment: Your certificate is not wildcard certificate. Please check this link.
https://grownis.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate is not wildcard certificate. Please check this link.

https://grownis.com/

The confirmation link is https://grownis.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=CONRIMATION_TOKEN

You will need to make a redirection from non-www to www or purchase wildcard certificate.

Comment: This actually makes sense, I didn't notice that. I will take a deeper look and mark your answer as correct after confirming. It's strange though that "grownis.com" redirects to "www.grownis.com" but if you prepend the "https://" the redirect does not work. Any idea? I have updated the post with the redirect setup I had in place

Comment: I see. I saw the screenshot attached. But I can't see the condition of that rule. Can you attach the screenshot of it also?